# Como rodar arquivos .mkv em todos navegadores?

Tags: html5, html5-video, cross-browser

Eu estou tentando rodar um vídeo em `.mkv` no Firefox, porém o mesmo da erro devido a extensão do arquivo.

Há alguma forma de fazer o vídeo funcionar?

```
<video>
    <source src="video.mkv" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Usando o código acima o erro retornado é:

> Formato de vídeo ou tipo MIME não Suportado

Comment: E o que você já fez? Poderia [edit] e mostrar qual o seu código?

Comment: @Stormwind `<video controls="true" autoplay="true">
 <source src="video.mkv" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

Comment: Você tem esse vídeo? Ele está na pasta junto com o arquivo HTML?

Comment: tenho, no google chrome abre, porem no firefox nao

Comment: Na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) não diz nada sobre o elemento `<video>` dar suporte ao fomato `.mkv`.

Comment: existe algo que eu possa fazer para poder rodar este video no navegador?

Comment: O mesmo dá erro. Mas que erro? Tente arrastar esse vídeo para o navegador e veja se o mesmo roda normalmente.

Comment: Formato de video ou tipo MIME nao Suportado

Answer (score 5):

O HTML não suporta nenhum formato de vídeo, e o HTML5 [não especifica quais formatos os navegadores devem suportar](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-video-element).

[Cabe então aos navegadores decidir quais formatos eles escolhem suportar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats). Aparentemente, o Chrome roda `.mkv`,entretanto não é uma obrigação dos outros navegadores reproduzirem o mesmo arquivo. Tanto que, repentinamente pode desaparecer esse suporte, e você irá ter problemas para executar o vídeo.

Você até pode encontrar algo que não seja oficial, mas a garantia que irá funcionar na primeira vez e ficar funcionando é algo sem resposta.

---

A **solução de verdade**, é utilizar o formato mais recomendado para a tag `<video>` o [WebM](https://www.webmproject.org/), ou um dos seguintes:

- audio/midi,
- audio/mpeg,
- audio/webm,
- audio/ogg,
- audio/wav

---

Também temos uma pergunta respondida sobre isso no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9622726).

Comment: não há algum player que eu possa utilizar ex: Jwplayer, Flow Player etc...

Comment: @CarlosdaSilva não é o player que "roda" o video, o player internamente usa codecs, esses codecs podem vir do sistema operacional (tipo xpcodec ou klitecodec) ou pode ser nativos do navegador, como no chrome, então se o chrome ou o sistema operacional não tiver o codec nunca vai rodar. A unica maneira garantida de faze algo funcionar é mudar o formato do video.

Answer (score 2):

A extensão `.mkv` e `.mp4` não tem nada haver com o formato do video, você poderia renomear um arquivo com o **formato mp4** para a extensão `video.foobaz` que ainda seria um arquivo `.mp4`.

Videos não são reproduzidos simplesmente pelo HTML, a tag `<video>` depende dos CODECs instalados na máquina ou que veem com o navegador:

> Wiki: CoDec é o acrônimo de Codificador/Decodificador, dispositivo de hardware ou software que codifica/decodifica sinais.

Se você tem um CODEC instalado em **seu computador** para MKV que seja compátivel com o mesmo tipo de arquitetura da compilação do seu navegador, que pode ser x86 ou x64 (outras vezes *arm*), então irá funcionar em **seu computador**, isso não quer dizer que irá funcionar em outros navegadores.

Então se você tem um navegador x64, precisará de um codec x64, existe um pacote de codecs chamado [*k-lite codec*](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), que contém x86/x64 embutidos, ou seja ele instala para ambos, o pacote básico que é o mais leve suporta mkv: https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_basic.htm

Todos formatos suportados (**não tem haver com extensões**) são:

- AVI, MKV, MP4, FLV, MPEG, MOV, TS, M2TS, WMV, RM, RMVB, OGM, WebM

Ao instalar é recomendado que reinicie o computador, claro que como eu já disse isso só vai fazer o seu navegador reconhecer, para que funcione em outros computadores será necessário instalar os codecs também.

---

### Como funcionar em "todos" (quase todos) navegadores modernos

Não tem como garantir que funcione em todos navegadores, o Chrome já vem com muitos codecs, mas o `mkv` **não** é um deles, a única solução viável é re-codificar o video para um novo formato que seja mais comum como o próprio formato MPEG-4 ou H.264 (ambos geralmente usam a extensão `.mp4`), você pode converter manualmente usando softwares como:

- [freemake](http://www.freemake.com/how_to/how_to_convert_video_to_h.264) (não conheço a qualidade do software, é apenas um exemplo, existem outros no "mercado")

Ou você pode converter no lado do servidor, durante o upload, usando o `ffmpeg` que é um programa voltado para isto, por exemplo:

```
ffmpeg -i videoupado.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy videoupado.mp4
```

Em PHP poderia usar `exec`, após o upload, por exemplo:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i videoupado.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy videoupado.mp4', $output);

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Já testei esse freemake, mas não gostei muito. Prefiro o AVS. :)